# CSS Transformations with Font Awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use CSS transformations with an `a` tag and a `i`. So far I have tried to target by adding a class/id to the a tag and the i tag. Also targeting each .fa class. I either get the text or the icon to rotate. Not both.

[image]

Link to codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woRyMG

```
 <div class="float-nav">
      <i class="fa fa-compass fa-4x menu-btn"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <!-- <a href="" class="fa fa-home">Home</a> -->
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" id="one" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-terminal" aria-hidden="true"></i>Projects</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>Blog</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>CV</a>
  </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <header>
        <div class="header-background">
          <div class="header-text">
            <p>Some Text Here </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </header>

    </div>



body,
html,
header,
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.main-nav,
.float-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-nav {
  /*display: none; toggle this to see animation on click*/
}

.main-nav a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.main-nav a:first-child {
  color: orange;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

.main-nav a:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
}

.main-nav a:nth-child(3) {
  color: yellow;
}

.main-nav a:nth-child(4) {
  color: blue;
}

.active-nav {
  display: block;
}

.header-background {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/900x900") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In Your example, there is transformation with only -webkit- prefix of `<a>` tag. You should rotate `<i>` tag right? And add transformation without prefix.

Comment: Doing .main-nav i:first-child only rotates the font awesome icon and leaves the text as is. The prefix doesn't change the transformation.

Comment: What is the goal then? What should be rotated and when?

Comment: I added an image to my question and updated it. I realized it wasn't asked that well. I am trying to rotate both the text and the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `display: inline-block` or `display: block` in `.main-nav a.`. It should be:

```
.main-nav a {
  display: inline-block; /* Or block. Depends of what You need */
  margin-right: 2px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

Also add `transform` without prefix to `.main-nav a:first-child`. So it will be:

```
.main-nav a:first-child {
  color: orange;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
```

Remember - unprefixed AFTER prefixed.

Comment: Thanks! Inline fixed it.

Comment: It's common problem with transformations. They doesn't work without appropriate `display` value.